# Python function decorator calls

Tags: python, decorator

I have a function that is called about 1742 times but when i do a decorator to calculate each call time of it i found that it prints only 647 times i don't know why that happens.

Update:

- My problem here is not with how to make timing its with the difference between the number of calls, I want a way to make a decorator like function that have accurate calls.
- My python version is 2.6 and here is the module i am working on http://pastebin.com/MXu1pLWM
- In the profiling output i found that the caller function to the decorated function calls it only 647 and it was the only caller function!!.

**Figured out!**

- The function that i decorated have a loop in it with length of 1742 but the actual calls to the function is only 647, although i still not understand why it says 1742 in calls section instead of 647 :)

---

```
number = 0
def timing(f):
    def wrap(*args):
        time1 = time.time()
        ret = f(*args)
        time2 = time.time()
        global number
        number+=1
        print '%s function took %0.6f ms No of calls: %s' % (f.func_name, ((time2-time1)), str(number))
        return ret
    return wrap
```

Comment: This is a horrible way to be timing function calls. Have a look at python profilers: http://docs.python.org/library/profile.html

Comment: This is not how you do profiling in Python.

Comment: Provide more evidence. The decorator code looks fine. I am not believing your claim...

Comment: Python already has the [timeit](http://docs.python.org/library/timeit.html) module to do this sort of thing.

Comment: @RestRisiko actually i profiled my application and i found that timing is called 1 time and wrap is called 647 and the function that i decorated is called 1742 time!!

Comment: Nothing I do believe....

Comment: I've tried it myself. What you describe doesn't happen - as expected, what you describe would be a **severe** bug and wouldn't go unnoticed for a week. Post more details (Python version, how you run it, perhaps other code involved if not too much) or we can't help.

Comment: threading can mess with the counter, but the difference should be like 10% less, not 70%. The code is fine and works fine, if you hope to get a answer you will have to post runable code that actually produces the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I saw your pasted code - on the pastebin. The problem is that you are wrapping the `__iter__` method of a class. It is only called once for each loop that is started. And it shoud return imediatelly with an iterator object -- what would be profilable is the calls to the "next" method on the object returned by `__iter__` (this is what is called in each `for` loop interacton).

Which means that without changing anything, instead of using your profiler as a decorator on a call to `__iter__` you'd use that code in some other way around the `yield` statement inside taht `__iter__`

Other than that, you will be better of using timeit.timeit or other already existing profiles to avoid such traps, as are listed on the comments.